# How to substitute a value in a variable

Tags: unix, sh

Good day,

I have a simple UNIX script test.sh

I need to substitute the value of a variable.
This variable contains a directory path.

My test.sh script

```
#!/bin/sh
filepath="/host/messages/in/documents"
archivePath=`${filepath/\/in/\/archive/}`
echo "archive path is " $archivePath
```

I get a "bad substitution" error when I run it.

The required output for archivePath should be:

```
/host/messages/archive/documents
```

What am I doing wrong and what could be a possible solution?

Comment: Wrong: not reading the shell's manual page. Solution: read the shell's manual page. And keep in mind that not all the world's a bash. Substitution is not a feature of POSIX shells, it's an extension of some other shells (bash and zsh come to mind). Note: the backticks cause **process substitution**, not **parameter substitution**.

Comment: If not substitute, then how do I replace 'in' to 'archive'?.

Answer (score 1):

Must use bash (or ksh or zsh), use correct syntax `${varname/pattern/replacement}` and escape `/` by `\` in `pattern` and `replacement`.

```
#!/bin/bash
filepath="/host/messages/in/documents"
archivePath="${filepath/\/in\//\/archive\/}"
echo "archive path is $archivePath"
```

Comment: i dont' have bash, ksh or zsh on my UNIX OS.

Comment: Really? What do `ls -l /bin/sh` and `/bin/sh --version` say?
Plain POSIX sh cannot recognize `${varname/pattern/replacement}` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution with sed:

```
#!/bin/sh
filepath="/host/messages/in/documents"
echo $filepath | sed -e %s/in/archive/g
archivePath=`echo $filepath | sed -e s/in/archive/g`
echo "archive path is $archivePath"
```